# grails createCriteria for date calculation

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to fetch data from database using `criteria`

`Domain class` Invoice -

```
class Invoice{
    Date invoiceNo
    Date invoiceDate
    int interval

    static constraints = { }
    }
```

`criteria` module from the `controller`

```
if(!params.sort && !params.order) {
            params.sort = "invoiceDate + interval" //invoiceDate+ interval
            params.order = "asc"
        }
        def c = Invoice.createCriteria()
        def results = c.list(params) {
            between("invoiceDate+ interval", invoiceDate, invoiceDate+ interval)

        }
```

I want to calculate `dueDate` from the `invoiceDate` & `interval`.

i want a result like this

```
invoiceNo | invoiceDate | interval| dueDate    |
001       | 2016-09-30  | 5       | 2016-10-05 |
002       | 2016-09-15  | 5       | 2016-09-20 |
```

Comment: What problem / error are you getting?

Comment: i dont have field for result `invoiceDate+ interval` then impossible that code will work..

Comment: @AbhinandanSatpute see my domain class, i just have `invoiceNo` , `invoiceDate` and `interval`, but i am trying to get a field from `invoiceDate` + `interval`, for example `invoiceDate` = `2016-09-30 00:000:00` and `interval ` = 5 ,  then the result mustbe `2016-10-05 00:00:00`

Comment: Can you add more explanation about what are you trying to achieve and what problems you are facing, please?

Comment: So, in simple words `dueDate` will be `invoiceDate` + `interval`, right?

Comment: @AbhinandanSatpute exactly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124607/discussion-between-abhinandan-satpute-and-akiong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will insist you to modify your `Domain class` to add `derived field` as given below.

Modified `Domain class` - adding derived field `dueDate`

```
class Invoice{
Date invoiceNo
Date invoiceDate
int interval

//new field added
Date dueDate //Derived filed- will not persisted to the database

static mapping = {
   //formula to calculate dueDate (invoiceDate + interval)
    dueDate formula:"ADDDATE(invoice_date, interval)"
}

static constraints = { }
}
```

`criteria` code snippet- to fetch the invoices whose `dueDate` is in between `current Date` and `current Date + 7`.

```
def criteria = Invoice.createCriteria()

   Date currentDate =  new Date()

   //fetching data based on the criteria
   List invoiceList = criteria.list {
         between('dueDate', currentDate, (currentDate + 7))
     }
```